# Track Admob Event in the Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, admob

Is it possible to track `Admob` event that the user clicked on the ads in the `Google Analytics` .

I use `AdMob` for showing ads. I want to track every click on ads in `Google Analytics`.
How can I set up `Event`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution.

Implement the `AdMob` interface `AdListener` for your `Activity`.

```
public interface AdListener {
  public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad);
  public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, AdRequest.ErrorCode error);
  public void onPresentScreen(Ad ad);
  public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad);
  public void onLeaveApplication(Ad ad);
}
```

Then set listener for `AdView` element.

```
adView.setAdListener(this);
```

And override `onPresentScreen` method for tracking events if user clicks on Ads.

> onPresentScreen - Called when an Activity is created in front of your
>   app, presenting the user with a full-screen ad UI in response to their
>   touching ad.

```
private GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;
...
@Override
public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
    tracker.trackEvent(
            "AdMob",    // Category
            "AdView",   // Action
            "Clicked",  // Label
            1);         // Value
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the new google play services api:

```
    // from google-play-services.jar
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;

    AdListener adListener = new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
                tracker.trackEvent(
                "AdMob",    // Category
                "AdView",   // Action
                "Clicked",  // Label
                1);  
        }
    };
```

In new API AdListener is no longer an interface - it is abstract class:

```
    public abstract class AdListener {
      public void onAdLoaded() {}
      public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {}
      public void onAdOpened() {}
      public void onAdClosed() {}
      public void onAdLeftApplication() {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently AdMob provides default integration with google analytics. We just need to link analytics account with Admob.

Reference: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3508177?hl=en-GB